# Did any sect/denomation ascribe divinity to a person?

Tags: history, shirk, sects, divine-attributes

Did any sect/denomination ascribe divinity to a person in the history of Islam ? If yes, what sect/denomination and who was the person? Also what were their basis for that ?

Comment: Divinity as in Godliness? Several sub-sects within Shias and Sunnis do that to Mohammed and different Imams.

Comment: Yes. As Godliness.

Answer (score 1):

Ascribing divinity to a person would be considered [shirk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_%28Islam%29) (associating others with Allah), which is considered the worst sin, and implies disbelief in Islam.

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And **he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin**.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48)</sub>

It would violate [tawheed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawhid) (the oneness of God), part of the [shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada), the first [pillar of Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Pillars_of_Islam).  You can almost flick to a random page in the Qur'an and find warnings about not committing shirk.

If a group ascribed divinity to a person, it would not be recognized as an Islamic group.

Comment: Well what you say is not wrong but I still wonder if there are some self-described muslim communities that ascribe divinity to certain persons. I'm aware that they won't be considered as muslims from an orthodox point of view.

Answer (score -2):

Some Shiaa sects regard Ali as divine and the Qadiani also regard their leader Mirza Ghulam as a divine blessing

Comment: Some more elaboration and evidences please ... see [answer].

Comment: its an ideology, there's no book!